# Как правильно задать выражение в matlab?

Tags: математика, matlab

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается получить нужный результат. Вот как записываю я:

```
b=(y^(abs(x)^(1/3))+(cos(y)^3))*(abs(x-y)*(1+(sin(z)^2)/sqrt(x+y))/(exp(abs(x-y))+(x/2)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет звёздочек там где нужно и скобки неправильно расставлены. Правильно так:

```
b=y^(abs(x)^(1/3))+(cos(y)^3)*(abs(x-y)*(1+(sin(z)^2)/sqrt(x+y))/(exp(abs(x-y))+(x/2)))
```